# Javascript formatting numbers API

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems with my (javascript) API. When I use the coinmarketcap API (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker). As for "max_supply" for bitcoin, it gives me "16865112.0" in text. This is a problem. I want to automatically put comma's in the number like 16,865,112.0.

If the data id is for example ethereum (it doesnt have a max supply) it gives me  ∞. That works.

Original:

```js
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "bitcoin") {
      $("#max_supply").html(data[i].max_supply == null ? '∞' : data[i].max_supply);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="max_supply"></div>
```

This gives me an output of "21000000.0"

This is what i got so far

```js
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == "bitcoin") {
      $("#max_supply").html(Number(data[i].max_supply).toLocaleString('en-US') == null ? '∞' : data[i].max_supply.toLocaleString('en-US'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="max_supply"></div>
```

This doesn't give me an output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No way has this not already been answered on this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: @Feathercrown I have looked at other asked question but I couldnt figure it out, so that why i'm asking

Comment: @PatrickHund I have looked at that question but I still couldnt figure out what i have done wrong

Comment: Can you supply the code where you tried it?

Comment: Error messages? Expected output? Observed output?

Comment: @Feathercrown  I have edited my question

Comment: @PatrickHund I have edited my question

Comment: It looks like you’re getting confused by the ternary operator.  Try writing out an if/else instead, it should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should take off the `-1` in your for loop, or you will be missing the last item.

The ternary `maxSupply = maxSupply == null ? '∞' : numberWithCommas(maxSupply)` below says if max supply value is null (for the current coin from the JSON) then set maxSupply to `∞` else set maxSupply var to `numberWithCommas(maxSupply)`

I got the `numberWithCommas(...)` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/1309377 to help format the number with commas like you asked for.

I also switched to `.append()` instead of `.html()` otherwise you will just be writing over yourself.

```js
$.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/", function(data, status) {

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var coin = data[i].id;
    var maxSupply = data[i].max_supply;
    maxSupply = maxSupply == null ? '∞' : numberWithCommas(maxSupply)
    $("#max_supply").append(coin + ": " + maxSupply + "<br/>");
  }

});

function numberWithCommas(x){
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Max Supply</span>
<div id="max_supply"></div>
```